# Getting Error in Apache web server log file : called too early to check prototype

Tags: apache, webserver, error-log

I am new to this stuff so I am not able to identify where exactly the problem lies.
I am calling `update.cgi` from the form action of an html page named update.html. The cgi is responsible to update the file which is lying on the server.
But it fails to update and I am getting the error like this in error logs :-

```
update.cgi: main::redirect1() called too early to check prototype at /opt/apache/html/cgi-bin/linux/update.cgi line 17., referer: http://3.26.224.215/settings/Update.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Perl error. The redirect1() function is called before it is defined/declared.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/prog/ch33_01.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply...!!! But I didn't get the issue resolved using your solution..